# Define area with object in image

Tags: python, python-2.7

What would you suggest to identify the minimum rectangular selection to contain an object from an image?

I've a 3000x4000ish image which is mostly plain but with an object inside, I'd like to automate and make python recognize this (and by recognize I mean delimit the area with the object) and then make a "new" image which is the minimum rectangular selection including the object?

So for instance the red contour defines the image, the black one is the object while the blue one is the new image I'd like to have python recognize on itself.

Unlucky I can't just use a threshold because reasons.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

If you can use library `PIL` (that AFAIK is present on Linux and you can obtain it on Windows) then I can propose you two solutions:
1. Cleaner, 40 seconds for 4000x3000 image.

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('test.png', 'r')

def isHorizontalWhite(y):
    return all([im.getpixel((x,y)) == (255,255,255) for x in range(im.width)])
nonWhiteHorizontals = [y for y in range(im.height) if not isHorizontalWhite(y)]

def isVerticalWhite(x):
    return all([im.getpixel((x, y)) == (255, 255, 255) for y in range(im.height)])
nonWhiteVerticals = [x for x in range(im.width) if not isVerticalWhite(x)]

assert nonWhiteHorizontals or nonWhiteVerticals, "Image seems to be blank"

cropped = im.crop((min(nonWhiteVerticals), min(nonWhiteHorizontals), max(nonWhiteVerticals)+1, max(nonWhiteHorizontals)+1))
cropped.save('edited.png')
```

Idea of this code is simple: identify horizontal and vertical lines that are not white, take minimums and maximums and this will define the border.

2. Less clean solution, 9 seconds for 4000x3000 image.

```
im = Image.open('test.png', 'r')
pixels = im.getdata()

def getPixel(x,y):
    return pixels[x + y * im.width]

def isHorizontalWhite(y):
    return all([getPixel(x,y) == (255,255,255) for x in range(im.width)])
nonWhiteHorizontals = [y for y in range(im.height) if not isHorizontalWhite(y)]

def isVerticalWhite(x):
    return all([getPixel(x,y) == (255, 255, 255) for y in range(min(nonWhiteHorizontals), max(nonWhiteHorizontals)+1)])
nonWhiteVerticals = [x for x in range(im.width) if not isVerticalWhite(x)]

assert nonWhiteHorizontals or nonWhiteVerticals, "Image seems to be blank"

cropped = im.crop((min(nonWhiteVerticals), min(nonWhiteHorizontals), max(nonWhiteVerticals)+1, max(nonWhiteHorizontals)+1))
cropped.save('edited.png')
```

Two major optimizations have been done here:
First, instead of accessing the image many times to ask for singular pixels, we load all the pixels to some list-like structure and access them this way.
Second, is that since we know that for all points such that their x coordinate is from the one of the interval `(0, min(nonWhiteVerticals)), (max(nonWhiteVerticals), im.width)` are all white, so when searching for non-white horizontals, we don't need to check them at all.

Still this solution could be optimized if I only knew more about your problem. For example algorithm could be optimized if:

1. We know the object in the middle is big so it won't be cropped that much.
2. We know that object is a "one piece" (all non-white pixels are connected to each other).

Please let us know if performance of those algorithms are good enough for you.